# ASP.NET page causing NullReferenceException even though properties assigned in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a function within a vbthml page, below:

```
@If IsPost = True Then
    Dim cn As DBConn
    Dim arr(0 To 3) As Object

    cn.Connstr = "kbl"

    arr(0) = Request.Form("comments")
    arr(1) = Session("userObject").username
    arr(2) = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values("id")
    arr(3) = Now()

    Call cn.InsertSQL("addForumPost", arr)
End If
```

A couple of points:

- `DBConn` is a class I wrote
- When I debug and look at `cn.connstr`, the value is "kbl" as expected
- The array values are populated as expected

The strange thing is, if I add a watch for "cn", it returns Nothing, and I get the

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

error on the `Call cn.InsertSQL` line. The thing I'm confused about is how can the `cn.connstr` property be populated if `cn` is nothing?

Thanks,

Terry

Comment: `Dim cn As New DBConn` you need to instantiate the class. Also show the DBConn class, that would help. IMHO look into using a list as well instead of defining an array like you are.

Comment: Hey, thanks I’ll look into the list idea, will that work with different data types?  I did try New, but got the same error.  I still don’t get why it would successfully assign the value of them connstr property if the object isn’t instantiated?

Comment: the NullReferenceException is because something is not instantiated. Can you include the code for DBConn?

Comment: It will work with different types. Again, please show the DBConn class so we can further help you.

Comment: I must have missed a Save when trying the New before, because I tried it today and it fixed it, thanks!  If you want to post as the answer I'll mark it.