# <function> is not a member of <class> error when published to Azure

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure, razor

I'm working on an MVC app and I have built a function to handle my DB connections called DBConn.  Within DBConn I have a function InsertSQL(qry, parr()) that is public and shared.  When I test on my local machine it all works fine, but when I publish to Azure and view the live site I get the following:

> BC30456: 'InsertSQL' is not a member of 'DBConn'.

The Function I have is below:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Public Class DBConn
    Public Shared Connstr As String
    Public Shared Querystr As String

    Public Shared Function InsertSQL(qryStr As String, ByRef parr() As Object) As Integer
        Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim qry As String = ""

        connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(Connstr).ConnectionString
        connection.Open()

        cmd.Connection = connection

        Select Case qryStr
            Case "addForumPost"
                qry = "INSERT INTO ForumPosts(CreatedBy, CreatedDate, Sticky, Message, ForumID) VALUES ('" & parr(1) & "','" & parr(3) & "'," & "0" & ",'" & parr(0) & "'," & parr(2) & ")"

        End Select

        If qry <> "" Then cmd.CommandText = qry

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        connection.Close()

        Return 0
    End Function
End Class
```

I've only included the InsertSQL function for brevity, but there are other functions set up exactly the same way that aren't having the same issue.  Any ideas?  I'm thinking it must be either an Azure thing, or an access/permission thing.

Here is how I am calling the function within my asp page:

```
@<form method = "post" action="@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath">
                            <fieldset>
                                <p>Add Comment</p>
                                <p><textarea style="width:100%" rows="10" name = "comment" ></textarea></p>
                                <p><input type = "submit" name="addPost" value="Post" /></p>

                            @If IsPost = True Then
                                Dim rtnCode As Integer
                                Dim cn As New DBConn
                                Dim arr(0 To 3) As Object

                                If Request.Form("comment") <> "" Then
                                    cn.Connstr = "kbl"

                                    arr(0) = Request.Form("comment")
                                    arr(1) = Session("userObject").username
                                    arr(2) = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values("id")
                                    arr(3) = Now().ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss")

                                    rtnCode = cn.InsertSQL("addForumPost", arr)
                                End If
                                @<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>
                            End If

                            </fieldset>

                        </form>
```

Comment: I don't think you need an instance of DBConn to use a shared method. Try deleting `Dim cn As New DBConn` Then `rtnCode = DBConn.InsertSQL("addForumPost", arr)`

Comment: I thought that, originally I didn't instantiate it but got the error I asked for help with in this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52471605/asp-net-page-causing-nullreferenceexception-even-though-properties-assigned-in-v?noredirect=1

Comment: Don't declare cn at all. Then use the name of the class when you call your method , not a variable of the class type. `DBConn.InsertSQL`

Comment: OK thanks, I'll give it a go.  I'll have to assign the connstr value in the function, but that's probably a better way of doing it anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix it.  The thing I don't understand is why it works on my local machine, but not when I publish to Azure?